# How to remove Circular dependency in project reference

Tags: c#, .net-core

For the new requirement, I was changing the existing solution structure. so, when the changing i was facing the issue of circular dependency reference project. there are 3 class library.

1. **Book** library contains **Book.cs** class. In this class there is a method **GetMap** in that i'm call **Get** Method from **Common library**.
2. **CustomBook** library contains **CustomBook.cs** which inherits **Book** class.
3. **Common** library which contains **CallingCall.cs** has **GET** Method in this class we are initializing the CustomBook class. To initialize, I'm adding the reference of Book library project to Common library. then i was facing the circular dependency.

Please help me out from this issue.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: there is only 1 solution, re-organise your assemblies so you dont have a circular dependency. Is there a good reason to have separate assemblies in the first place?

Comment: As I understand, The common library should be the bottom of layers. That's way you need to remove codes related Books and CustomBooks codes in the common library.

Comment: A lot of people make the mistake of thinking layers == projects. It's perfectly possible to layer an application well inside a single project.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, we need in separate libraries only

Comment: The question would benefit from some clarifications. Is `Get` a static or instance method? if the later for what type? Is the `Get` method called from `GetMap` the same as in `CallingCall`? Why does the `Get` method need to create a `customBook`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Common` library cannot reference any other library. So, remove all the code that needs to reference something else into a new library, or move it to existing library, or move it to the main app. Or move all the referenced code into a big freaky `Common` library. These 4 options are pretty much all the options you have.